# Simple Division on "Form" with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something which I thought was very simple, but apparently I'm having trouble doing it.

I have two input fields on a page ('sales', 'fees'). A third input field should be the value of 'fees' divided by 'sales'.

One caveat: I don't want a standard form where they have to "submit" it. I just want it to automatically update with the value (least amount of effort on the users part).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sale = document.getElementById('sales').value;
    var fee = document.getElementById('fees').value;
    document.getElementById('rate').value = sale / fee;
</script>
```

and

```
<p>Total purchases: <input type="text" name="sales" id="sales" /></p>
<p>Total fees: <input type="text" name="fees" id="fees" /></p>
<p>Your net rate is: <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" /></p>
```

I'm assuming there is some way to set the `value="..."` for `id="rate"` and I'm probably with off-base with my attempt, but I'm hoping someone might be able to help me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: The answers provided below are great, but if you are interested this is something that Angular would handle really nicely for you - see the second example here http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp - apologies if you have no interest in this, but thought it might be worth showing you

Answer (score 1):

You can either set this on a `blur` event or something similar, but you can also run it on an interval to just update automatically.  change the `100` in the `setInterval` call to a larger number to see it take some time to refresh.

The javascript you had ran once on page load, and that was it.

I also added some basic error checking.

```js
function calculateNetRate(){
  
  var sale = document.getElementById('sales').value;
    var fee = document.getElementById('fees').value;
  sale = isNaN(sale) ? 0 : sale;
  fee = isNaN(fee) ? 0 : fee;
  var netRate = fee > 0 ? sale / fee : NaN;
    document.getElementById('rate').value = isNaN(netRate) ? 0 : netRate;
  
}

setInterval(function(){
  
  calculateNetRate();
  }, 100);
```

```html
<p>Total purchases: <input type="text" name="sales" id="sales" /></p>
<p>Total fees: <input type="text" name="fees" id="fees" /></p>
<p>Your net rate is: <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting to integer; use `parseInt()`

```
var sale = parseInt(document.getElementById('sales').value);
var fee = parseInt(document.getElementById('fees').value);
document.getElementById('rate').value = sale / fee;
```

Also you need a button for `onclick`, or alterantively you can use `onchange` on fields

```
<button onclick="run()">calculate</button>
```

now wrap your code into  run() function

```
function run(){

var sale = parseInt(document.getElementById('sales').value);
var fee = parseInt(document.getElementById('fees').value);
document.getElementById('rate').value = sale / fee;

}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
function run(){

var sale = parseInt(document.getElementById('sales').value);
var fee = parseInt(document.getElementById('fees').value);
document.getElementById('rate').value = sale / fee;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Total purchases: <input type="text" name="sales" id="sales" /></p>
<p>Total fees: <input type="text" name="fees" id="fees" /></p>
<p>Your net rate is: <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" /></p>
<button onclick="run()">calculate</button>
```

Comment: Be sure to use the `radix` parameter of `parseInt` to ensure consistent and predictable behavior (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: who that i missed ever since will read more about it @jrubins thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use buttons or submit on forms, use **onKeyPress** event on the second  input box. And create a function to call for that event.

You html code where to call the function:

```
<p>Total fees: <input type="text" name="fees" id="fees" onKeypress="myFunc()"/></p>
```

and your javascript code:

```
function myFunc() {
    var sale = document.getElementById('sales').value;
    var fee = document.getElementById('fees').value;
    document.getElementById('rate').value = sale / fee ;
}
```

But your code will surely get an error like Infinity or NaN.
Here is a good reference about that issue, visit [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp) site.